# Can't read html file title Jsoup in Android application

Tags: java, android, jsoup, java-io

I am trying to parse HTML files from my local file system using Jsoup. I have created a small Android application, where the user can input filename and gets the title of the HTML file displayed in TextView. However, each time I try to get the title from the Document element, I get null. How can I fix this error?
Here is my code for the button click function:

```
 public void onClick(View view){
        MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
        myTask.execute();
    }
lass MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        String title;

     @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Document doc = null;
            File file = new File("file:///android_asset/olx.html");

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.parse(file, "UTF-8");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (doc != null)
                title = "success" + doc.title();
            else
                title = "Error. Can't read title! ";

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            outputText.setText(title);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the html you are trying to parse?

Comment: @Justin I'm trying to parse this website `https://www.olx.ua/` by downloading the home page as html file.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this.

```
 String title = doc.select("head title").text();
```

Comment: The problem is not about displaying the title itself. It's more about Document object initialization as it is set to null for some reason.

Comment: If doc is null, you should check why. Try to examine what exception is thrown when you call  `doc = Jsoup.parse(file, "UTF-8");`. Is the file present and path is correct? Is there something wrong with the content that make jsoup fail to parse it?